# Trying to change return ticket date on group flight but travel agency is being difficult and airline reroutes to agency

Tags: bookings, airlines, tips-and-tricks, lufthansa, travel-agents

I'm a member in a student chorus that's going on tour to Hungary. Our director/the university booked and arranged the tour through a travel agency. I wasn't sure I'd get to join but about a month ago everything got confirmed.

I called the travel agent to see if I could change my return date. She was very rude and said nothing could be done because it's a group ticket, and that I would've needed to make these arrangements months ago.

On a whim, I called the airline this evening, and the representative let it slip that the date **can** be changed (no idea about fee), but the agent has to call the airline's support number and do it directly because they're the ones that booked it.

- Is this true?
- Is there a reason for the agent to not work with me? (I said I'd be willing to pay a fee)
- Most importantly: Is there a way around this on the airline's end?

Comment: The airline won't do anything because they don't own the booking - the agency does, so they need to be the ones that amend it.  You can present the fact that you know it can be changed to the agency, but they are under no actual obligation to make any change - in fact, do *you* have any authority to request a change from your end?  Has anyone at the university given you permission with the agency to make changes?

Comment: @Moo I agree, it should probably be the person who ordered for flights from the travel agent who should be requesting that change.